# How to unbind and then repurpose a default keybinding?

Tags: key-bindings, deletion

I want to test out a few alternative keybinding setups but I’m not sure what the simplest/most effective way to do that is.

I would like to have it so that instead of `C-d` being forward delete ("`delete-char`"  which is what it is by default), whenever I hold down `C-d` I can use the left (`kbd <left>`?) and right (`kbd <right>`?) arrow keys to delete backwards and forwards.

I can can’t even get unsetting `C-d` to work:
When I put `(global-set-key (kbd "C-d") 'nil)` in my `init.el` and `eval-last-sexp`, `C-d` seems to actually be disabled.
But if I `save-buffer` and close emacs, when I open a new instance, `C-d` is back to being a forward delete.

Once I get past that problem, the next problem is figuring out how to even express "while `C-d` is pressed,
`<left>`  and `<right>` arrow keys trigger `delete-backwards-char` and `delete-char` and if either are held down they will repeatedly call their functions"
in the init file in elisp.

If I can get this resolved the proper way, I can apply the solution to repurpose other default keybindings, but at this point I can't imagine solving this single case without some real guidance.

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: @Drew My mistake, thanks for informing me.

Comment: No problem at all. And yeah, it's not obvious. Thx.

Answer (score 2):

To find the key representation you can do this:

1. `C-x b *scratch*`
2. Type  whatever key you are interested in.  Don't bother about what `Emacs` does or doesn't do when you type those keys. In your case you would type `Ctrl-d`, followed by `Right Arrow`.
3. Do `C-h l`. You will see the following entries

```
 C-d     ;; delete-char
 <right> ;; right-char
 C-h l   ;; view-lossage
```

- Portion before the `;;` says what keys you pressed.  The portion after `;;` says the command they run. Based on the above information you know that `Ctrl-d` followed by `Right Arrow` is same as `C-d <right>`.  So, to bind a command to `Ctrl-d RightArrow` you need to use `(kbd "C-d <right>")`
- You want `C-d <right>` to run what `C-d` does.  The `lossage` says `C-d` is mapped to `delete-char`.  So, you would do

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-d <right>") 'delete-char)
```

4. When you put the above code in `.emacs` and re-start Emacs you will see the following error message

```
global-set-key: Key sequence C-d <right> starts with non-prefix key C-d
```

The above message is a fancy way of saying that you need to unbind `C-d`. You already know `C-d` is written as `(kbd "C-d")`.  So, you add

```
(global-unset-key (kbd "C-d"))
```

before you `global-set-key`.

---

This is the `lossage` information for all the keys that are relevant to the question

```
 C-d         ;; delete-char
 <backspace> ;; backward-delete-char-untabify
 C-d         ;; delete-char
 <right>     ;; right-char
 C-d         ;; delete-char
 <left>      ;; left-char
 C-h l       ;; view-lossage
```

If you follow the above process, this is what you will end up with  in your `~/.emacs`.

```lisp
(global-unset-key (kbd "C-d"))
(global-set-key (kbd "C-d <right>") 'delete-char)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-d <left>") 'backward-delete-char-untabify)
```

Comment: How would this make `C-d` act as a modifier key similar to `Shift`? Unless I am using this wrong, here I have to [`C-d`, then remove my hand from `C-d` and press `<left>`] each time I want to backward delete one character; so with the snippet above, I would have to write `C-d <left> C-d <left> C-d <left>` to delete "hey". Ideally I have it so that I can hold down `C-d` and *while* holding down `C-d`, I can press `<left> <left> <left>` or just hold down `<left>` do backwards delete the "hey".

Answer (score 1):

You need to save the configuration in your `~/.emacs`.

1. `C-x C-f` `~/.emacs`
2. Copy the following `elisp` snippet in to your `~/.emacs`

```lisp
(global-unset-key (kbd "C-d"))

(defvar my-Ctrl-d-map
  (let ((map (make-sparse-keymap)))
    (define-key map (kbd "<right>") 'delete-char)
    (define-key map (kbd "<left>") 'delete-backward-char)
    map))
    
(fset 'my-Ctrl-d-map my-Ctrl-d-map)

(map-keymap
 (lambda (key cmd)
   (put cmd 'repeat-map 'my-Ctrl-d-map))
 my-Ctrl-d-map)

(repeat-mode -1)
(repeat-mode 1)

(global-set-key (kbd "C-d") 'my-Ctrl-d-map)
```

3. Restart `Emacs`.

Note that `repeat-mode` is available in `Emacs` >= `28.1`

Comment: This does just about what I was hoping, but not quite: This snippet allows me to press `C-d` and then after releasing my hand from the `C-d` chord, I can press any combination from `(<left>*<right>*)*` or hold down in one direction and it will delete in that direction. I was hoping that I could get it so that *while* `C-d` is held down, the functionality is active, but as soon as I remove my hand from `C-d`, the `<left>` and `<right>` arrow keys go back to just being regular backward and forward movement. I am thinking similar to how the `Shift` key works. (Upvoted anyway for all your help)

Comment: Based on what you say, you are looking for the other solution https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/72443/31220.  The actual elisp snippet is at the bottom of that link.  FWIW, when you are in `repeat-mode`, when you press any key other than the repeated keys,  you will exit the `repeat-mode`.  Try doing `C-d <left> C-g <left> <right>`, see what happens.  You can replace `C-g` with any key, as long as it is different from `<left>` and `<right>`.  Try doing `C-d <left> a b <right> <left>`.

Comment: I replied to your other post. I think your other post moves further away from what I was originally looking for than this one. I'm sorry if I am not explaining clearly what kind of behavior I am looking for. Did my other comment clarify anything?